# AWS Node.js Lambda: Promise reject does not return custom error, resolve works

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm running a AWS Lambda function in Node.js 14, bound to a REST API in API Gateway with LAMBDA_PROXY.

Consider this simplified Pseudo Code for `index.js`:

```
exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
    if (event.body.myParam === '1') {
        // Works!
        return {
            statusCode: 302,
            headers: {
                Location: 'https://iam.aredire.ct'
            }
        };
    } else if (event.body.myParam === '2') {
        // Works! 403 - {"message":"You are not allowed to do that!"}
        return {
            statusCode: 403,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'You are not allowed to do that!'
            })
        };
    } else if (event.body.myParam === '3') {
        const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
        const token = 'ey...';
        const pubKey = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- ...';

        // Some promise
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            // Some async call
            jwt.verify(token, pubKey, function (err, decoded) {
                if (err) {
                    // gets logged
                    console.log(err);

                    // 502 - {"message": "Internal server error"}
                    return reject({
                        statusCode: 403,
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            message: 'No valid token'
                        })
                    });

                    // 502 - {"message": "Internal server error"}
                    return reject(JSON.stringify({
                        statusCode: 403,
                        body: {
                            message: 'No valid token'
                        }
                    }));
                }
                // Works! 200 - {"message":"Works!"}
                resolve({
                    statusCode: 200,
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        message: 'Works!'
                    })
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Please see the comments in the code snippets. Do you have any idea why `resolve()` and `return` work as expected but `reject()` always returns `502 - {"message": "Internal server error"}`? I want that the requester actually gets a `403 - {"message": "No valid token"}`?

I read about `JSON.stringifying` the whole error object, but that does not help.

Cloudwatch raises this error:

```
ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "{\"statusCode\":403,\"body\":{\"message\":\"No valid token\"}}",
    "stack": [
        ...
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Error Handling in Other Services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-exceptions.html#nodejs-exceptions-other-services):

> API Gateway treats all invocation and function errors as internal errors. If the Lambda API rejects the invocation request, API Gateway returns a 500 error code. If the function runs but returns an error, or returns a response in the wrong format, API Gateway returns a 502 error code. To customize the error response, you must catch errors in your code and format a response in the required format.

You should resolve the promise, rather than reject it, to indicate *to API Gateway* that it completed normally, and include the relevant 4xx statusCode and body to indicate *to your client* (not API Gateway) that it represents an application-level failure.

Comment: I must have overseen this paragraph, thank you! Makes sense to catch application-level errors by myself and not to pass them to API Gateway as errors.